# jQuery: Set 2 Decimal Places

Tags: jquery, decimal, decimalformat

I am calculating the width of my parent element (#projects) through sum the width of all child elements (.project). To avoid bugs I need add 2 decimal places to the width of the parent element. How is this possible?

```
$(window).on( "resize", function () {
   $(".project").width( $(window).width() / 3 );

   var sum=0;
   $("#projects .project").each( function(){ sum += $(this).width(); });
   $(".container").width( sum );
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `$(window).width() / 3` will obviously generate a float value if the width is not fully dividable by 3.

in order to force float values to have two digits in the result, you might use

```
var sum = 0.0;

...


$(".container").width( sum.toFixed(2) );
```

**Edit: please mind the fact that not all browser/versions can handle fractional pixels properly - `1.357px` might end in arbitrary results ...**

Comment: I have five child elements at which each comes with a width of 363.667px. Therefore, the parent element must be 363.667px*5 = 1818.335px wide but it still has a width of 1818px. Any ideas?

Comment: If you set the width of an element to 1818.335px it will be rounded to 1818px. There are no half pixels on your screen ...